# how do i get my deleted unrevisioned local file back in svn

Tags: svn

I am working on a project . The whole project is on svn repository. I copied a file from some place to my project . But did not commit it to repository . Now somebody else created the same file at same path as mine and added it to svn . 
The i did an svn up . It gave me conflict at the newly added file . TO resolve the conflict , I removed that file from my local copy and ran the following command

svn resolved file_name.
then i did svn up again. Later when i built the code i got error that the file i deleted is needed.

Now when i do svn up , its not restoring that file . I do not know whats the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revert local changes done to this file (even if you don't see it in your working copy) using `svn revert` and then run `svn update` again.

The file is not in Subversion and there is no way to restore it from the repository **if you didn't commit the file** to the repository (i.e. you didn't publish it). But since you say that someone else already committed it to the repo, the file has to be there and you should be able to restore it successfully in your local working copy.

Comment: but someone else has commited it to repository .And its in the repository now . But svn up is not restoring it

Comment: @PardeepKr In such case it should be easy to recover it, but I don't understand why `svn up` does not work for you. `svn checkout` a fresh working copy and see if the file is there.

Comment: i did that , and file is there . I do not understand why svn up is not restoring it .

Comment: Run `svn revert THISFILE` in your working copy and then `svn update`.

Comment: yeah , i just did that .its recovered